# Convergent series, root test

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Given $s_n$ with

$s_n := \sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}{a_n}\,\,with\,\,\, a_n := (1+\frac{1}{n})^n·x^n$
($n \in \mathbb{N}, x \in \mathbb{R})$

I'm trying to prove that $s_n$ is convergent for $|x| < 1$.

I already took care of proving divergence for $|x| \geqslant 1$, so the rest seemed quite straightforward to me by applying the root test.

$\sqrt[n]{|a_n|} = \sqrt[n]{|(1+\frac{1}{n})^n·x^n|} = \sqrt[n]{(1+\frac{1}{n})^n·|x|^n} = \sqrt[n]{(1+\frac{1}{n})^n}·\sqrt[n]{|x|^n} = (1 + \frac{1}{n}) \cdot |x|$

For the root test, we need to show that $(1 + \frac{1}{n}) \cdot |x| < 1$.

Consider that $\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty}(1 + \frac{1}{n}) = 1. \implies \exists n_0 \in \mathbb{N}:(1+\frac{1}{n})<1 + \varepsilon \,\forall n \geqslant n_0.$

Thus, $(1 + \frac{1}{n}) \cdot |x| < (1+\varepsilon)|x|.$

This is where I'm stuck, because there's no way that $(1+\varepsilon)|x| < 1.$

What did I do wrong? How can I show that show that $(1 + \frac{1}{n}) \cdot |x| < 1$?

Comment: You have assumed that $\lvert x\rvert < 1$. So you can pick an $\varepsilon > 0$ such that you still have $(1+\varepsilon)\lvert x\rvert < 1$.

Comment: Whoops, how embarrassing! Thanks for pointing this out. If you put it in as an answer, I can mark this question solved.

Comment: Also the series does not diverge when x=1. At x=1, series converges to $e$

Comment: @SwapnilTri With $x = 1$, we keep adding the limit of the left term (= $e$) to itself without it getting smaller in the next iteration of the sum (which is more or less exactly what $x$ is for). So, at $x = 1$, the sum will have the value $e$ + $e$ + $e$ + ... + $e$, up to infinity. Thus, this series will diverge.

Comment: @chiruno: Please edit your question. Write $\sum s_n$, not $S_n$. Got confused there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have assumed $\lvert x\rvert < 1$, you can pick an $\varepsilon > 0$ - depending on $\lvert x\rvert$ of course - such that you still have $(1+\varepsilon)\lvert x\rvert < 1$.

However, it is not necessary to actually pick an $\varepsilon$, since the root test asserts the absolute convergence of the series $\sum a_n$ if

$$\limsup_{n\to\infty} \sqrt[n]{\lvert a_n\rvert} < 1,$$

and here you have

$$\limsup_{n\to\infty} \sqrt[n]{\left(1+\tfrac{1}{n}\right)^n\lvert x\rvert^n} = \lim_{n\to\infty} \left(1+\tfrac{1}{n}\right)\lvert x\rvert = \lvert x\rvert < 1.$$